# Bloch's Theorem and its solutions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, bloch-sphere

I was reading Ali Omar text on solid state course and it said about the fact that electrons in a lattice or in a periodic lattice never scatters or make collisions with the positive ion cores, as the eigen functions of the solution of Bloch's theorem have infinite lifetime and eigen functions do not gets scattered?

I do not understand as why eigen functions never scatters and what does scattering of eigen functions means and also what does it mean by saying eigen functions has infinite life time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenstates of a given Hamiltonian are always stationary, which means that their square modulus is constant over time, and their time dependence is just a phase factor. This also happens for electrons moving on a lattice of positive ions, so the Bloch states are stationary or, if you wish, they have infinite lifetime.

The subtle point is the following: the Hamiltonian describing this system is a "single particle Hamiltonian", namely it is quadratic in the wave function. This means that the an eigenstate can be interpreted simply as a wave function associated to a single electron with given momentum. However this makes it impossible to describe phenomena like scattering of electrons with ions or interaction of electrons among themselves. To do that, we should include an interaction term in the Hamiltonian, and now the eigenstates are "many-body" states, which means that an eigenstate is **not** associated to a single particle, but is a collective state of all the particles. These states are again stationary.
However, in some cases one can still explain the physics with a picture of individual particles moving around, i.e. in terms of states which are similar to Bloch states, but with a negative exponential time-dependence.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the second part, but what about the part that eigen states do not scatters? Can you comment on it.

Comment: Sure: what is scattering with the ions? It is a process where the electron changes momentum and the lattice starts vibrating (a phonon mode is created). In the simplest model of electrons on a lattice, this process is disregarded and the dynamics of the lattice is totally neglected. As a result of this, the Bloch states of electrons have a fixed momentum and do not decay. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But still as we disregard dynamics of lattice, it still does not confirm that electron does not get scattered with the positive ion cores. So in real practice the question rolls back again as so do electron gets scattered by the positive ion cores or not?

Comment: We have to agree on the definition of "scattering" first. In my language, a scattering process is an event that results in an exchange of momentum between the electron and the lattice. In Bloch's theory this is disregarded completely because the lattice has no momentum, and it is just a background of fixed positive charges, and thus can just be treated as a background periodic potential for the electrons

Comment: Also, in real life scattering with the lattice is a real thing and it has important consequences in the transport properties (resistivity, thermal conductivity and so on...), but Bloch's theory, which is a first step to understand materials, neglects this aspect